# From a pool of webpages, finding pages similar to any given webpage

Tags: nlp, recommendation-engine, word2vec

I am given a set of webpages and I need to build a page recommender. Whichever URL is given to the application, the application should be able to find out pages from the given pool that are similar to the page at the URL.

---

I tried looking for different approaches to do that. The use of word2vec interested me. I am planning to crawl through all the given set of webpages and generate tags for that page based on the content in that page. From these tags I was hoping to use word2vec to calculate a vector value for the page and store it. When searching, I would caclulate vector for the given page in similar way to look for similar values. Is this the correct way of using word2vec? What training vector should be used? Any other better way to do this task?Or just plain text matching would be a better option?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using existing IR open source to handle your documents i.e. to index your crawled webpages and to query to get the results.
You can try to index document using [elastic](http://www.elastic.co) index all webpages and to query using [more like this query](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-mlt-query.html), from elastic documentation:

> The More Like This Query (MLT Query) finds documents that are "like" a given set of documents